# logical and operator not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

i am checking certain condition in documnet.ready and && operator is not working
code snippet 
lblvalue is empty.

```
$(function () {
 var lblValue = $("#lblRadioText").text();
    if (lblValue.length > 0 && hasWhiteSpace(lblValue) > 0) {
        $("#rdExportLastTime").css('display', 'inline');
    }
});

function hasWhiteSpace(text) {
    return text.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

can you tell me what is wrong.

Comment: try `if ((lblValue.length > 0) && (hasWhiteSpace(lblValue) > 0)) {` so that both statements are enclosed within their own parentheses.

Comment: try this ...if (lblValue.length > 0 && (hasWhiteSpace(lblValue) > 0)) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a boolean value out of `hasWhiteSpace()`, so you should skip the `> 0` in your conditional.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to check if your boolean value is great than 0.

You don't need the 2nd `> 0`:

```
if (lblValue.length > 0 && hasWhiteSpace(lblValue)) {
    $("#rdExportLastTime").css('display', 'inline');
}
```

Actually, that doesn't make any difference to the operation but it's still not needed.

The code seems to work fine to me (slightly adapted for testing):
http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/ZGAj5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is operator `&&` that fails?

What if you rewrite your code to:

```
var lblNotZero = lblValue.length > 0;
var hasWhiteSpace = hasWhiteSpace(lblValue) > 0;
if(lblNotZero && hasWhiteSpace)
{
  $("#rdExportLastTime").css('display', 'inline');
}
```

Now set a breakpoint (or output using `alert`) to check the values of `lblNotZero` and `hasWhiteSpace`.

Whenever you suspect language fundamentels such as `&&` not working correctly, rethink. Those are extremely well tested.